# PostgreSQL - Cant understand the data type of my data on world wide corona virus data

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, create-table, pgadmin

I have data(covid-19 deaths) in excel and I want to import the data into PGAdmin.

Here is the link of data https://ourworldindata.org/covid-deaths
Can you tell me what are the data types for different headings and how do I create the table/import my excel file into PostgreSQL?

Comment: GIYF my friend ;)

Answer (score 0):

These are all plain text files (.csv, .json, .xslx)

There are no datatypes. Its all string data. You should convert the data to appropriate data types either during the import process or load the data raw into a staging area and transform the data into appropriate data types from there.